# How can I assign a property value using 'With {...}' syntax?

Tags: vb.net, class, constructor

In the new Sub New , I want to Insert value of property

Ex:
1-Class

```
Public Class A

    Property Name As String

    Sub New()

        MsgBox(Name)   'Empty

    End Sub

End Class
```

2- Form

```
    Dim a As New A With {.Name = "ABCDE"}  'MsgBox Empty
```

Comment: Of course it is empty, you haven't set ("Insert"?) a value.  `Name = "ziggy"` will do it.  If you want to pass a name value to the class, add a string param to the constructor (`Sub New`) and pass the value.  You dont need curly braces using a param.

Comment: Sorry I mistook the form code and modified it

Comment: Move the message box out of the constructor and place it after `Dim a` and have it display `a.Name`.  The constructor is special, it runs to create the object.  `With` will assign the name *after* the object is created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Dim a As New A With {.Name = "ABCDE"}  'MsgBox Empty
```

The message box will be empty, because in the above statement the order of execution is:

- First `new` gets called and all the statements inside the subroutine `new` gets executed.
- Then the initialization step happens for the variables in `with` statement.

Now the alternate solution, if you want to print the name is during initialization:

You can print during property `set`, as shown below. (you can use a bool variable for not printing further when name is set a value.)

```
Public Class A

    'PROPERTY GET AND SET
    Private _name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
            MsgBox(_name) 'PRINT HERE
        End Set
    End Property

    'NEW SUBROUTINE
    Sub New()

    End Sub

End Class
```

calling:

```
 Dim a1 As New A With
            {.Name = "ABCDE"}
```